# Define empty data.table directly with the correct data type

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

In order to make my function more failsafe, I need to create an empty `data.table`, which does have a specific number of columns and a predefined data.type. This is to allow the later call to `dplyr::union` even though the data.table is empty.

Therefore, I would like to create an empty data.table and define the data types of the columns directly. This works for numeric or character columns, but fails for Date columns.

I found a possible solution by using entry 2.4 from the data.table FAQ, but it seems a bit weird to first fill the data.table with wrong values and remove them afterwards. [FAQ 2.4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#i-have-built-up-a-complex-table-with-many-columns.-i-want-to-use-it-as-a-template-for-a-new-table-i.e.-create-a-new-table-with-no-rows-but-with-the-column-names-and-types-copied-from-my-table.-can-i-do-that-easily)

Code to replicate the issue:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)


dt.empty <- data.table("Date" = character()
           , "Char.Vector" = character()
           , "Key.Variable" = character()
           , "ExchangeRate" = numeric()
)


dt.Union <- data.table( "Date" = as.Date(c("2000-01-01", "2001-01-01"))
                        , "Char.Vector" = as.character(c("a", "b"))
                        , "Key.Variable" = as.character(c("x1", "x2"))
                        , "ExchangeRate" = as.numeric(c(2,1.4))



)

dplyr::union(dt.Union
      , dt.empty)
Error: not compatible: 
- Incompatible type for column `Date`: x Date, y character
- Incompatible type for column `ExchangeRate`: x numeric, y character
```

I could solve this by using `dt.Union[0]` to create `dt.empty`, but I thought perhaps there exists an easier way to do this.

Comment: `"Date" = as.Date(character())` solves it, does it not? Also are you aware of `data.table::funion()`?

Comment: Does this answer the question? `data.table(
  Date = structure(integer(), class = 'Date'),
  Char.Vector = character(),
  Key.Variable = character(),
  ExchangeRate = double()
)`

Comment: Both comments actually solve the question. Is there perhaps a definition on how to get different data types? Because I couldn't easily find the information that `structure(integer(), class = 'Date')` is the correct call for a Date column.

Comment: I guess @IceCreamToucan's solution provides everything you need. If it is not an atomic type (character(), numeric(), etc.)  you can use `structure()`. Example: `structure(integer(), class = 'Factor')` .

Comment: @Ice Date is not integer, but OP could use IDate if desired. Personally, I just do x = Sys.Date()[0L] or similar. Can use dput(x) if interested in the structure() format. Also related: "templates" in the vetr package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can follow the advice of FAQ 2.4 the first time if you're not sure how to write a length-zero vector for some class:

```
> dput(dt.Union[0])
structure(list(Date = structure(numeric(0), class = "Date"), 
    Char.Vector = character(0), Key.Variable = character(0), 
    ExchangeRate = numeric(0)), row.names = c(NA, 0L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7ffd8d0ebee0>)
```

You can take the `list(...)` part out and your code becomes

```
myDT = setDT(list(
  Date = structure(numeric(0), class = "Date"), 
  Char.Vector = character(0),
  Key.Variable = character(0), 
  ExchangeRate = numeric(0)
))
```

More generally, `dput(x[0L])` will show code to recreate the zero-length version of any vector.

Comment: Related: vetr package, if this is part of your workflow; x[NA_integer_] to construct eg the missing value for a Date. Some notes here in case it's not clear: http://franknarf1.github.io/r-tutorial/_book/basics.html#na

Comment: Side note: data.table has funion so you shouldn't use dplyr::union on the data.table unless you've got it set up as a backend (by loading dtplyr etc)

Comment: Thanks for the idea with `dput` and a complete answer. On a side note: Is this a newly created account by the well-established expert Frank?

Comment: @hannes :) Yeah, account for use from work so I don't need to use my personal Google account to log in (as I always have in the past)